# Analogous WinForms Propertygrid in WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms, propertygrid

DO we have Analogous WinForms Propertygrid in WPF?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A good free wpf-based property grid?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820146/a-good-free-wpf-based-property-grid).  A google search could yield a more up to date list of implementations out there, but you're not going to find anything builtin.

Answer (score 1):

Not in the .NET Framework. You can use a WindowsFormsHost to use the Forms Property Grid, or you can look at one of the community implementations for WPF, like those (not sure which of them are still active):

http://wpg.codeplex.com/
http://wpfpropertygrid.codeplex.com/
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/87715/Native-WPF-4-PropertyGrid

Answer (score 0):

Or the property grid which is part of the [extended WPF toolkit](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/).